# how to filter email addresses from a text field

Tags: filter, ruby-on-rails-4, cpu-word

am working for a client who wants to filter email addresses from a textfield, where every text is analyzed and email addresses replaced by something like `#####$$$$`.

I appreciate your assistance in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find all email addresses in a text with a regex such as `/\S*\@\S*/` ([Test it on Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/KbRoGlF9Wq), might not be perfect) and then replace all matches with whatever you choose.

```
email_regex = /\S*\@\S*/
text = "This is test@example.com test string. Regex is regex@example.co.uk amazing."

result = text.gsub(email_regex, 'email_has_been_replaced')

p result
# => "This is email_has_been_replaced test string. Regex is email_has_been_replaced amazing."
```

In an ActiveRecord model:

```
class Post < AR::B
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\S*\@\S*/
  before_validation :remove_email_addresses_from_body

  private

  def remove_email_addresses_from_body
    self.body = body.gsub(EMAIL_REGEX, 'hidden_email')
  end
end
```

Comment: how do u put that in a model?

Comment: You could e.g. replace email addresses in a `before_save` or `before_validation` callback.